# How can I read a csv file and store it in a txt file using specifically csv-parser

Tags: node.js, csv-parser

I have this csv file:

```
country,year,population
USA,1952,8425333
USA,1957,9240934
...
```

want to store it in a txt file:

```
country,year,population
USA,1952,8425333
USA,1957,9240934
...
```

This is an assignment for school and we are required to use csv-parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');


const csvFile = fs.createReadStream('csv.csv');
const txtFile = fs.createWriteStream('txt.txt');

const csvParser = csv();

let head = false;

csvParser.on('data', function(data) {

        if (!head) {
            txtFile.write('country,year,population\r\n');
            head = true;
        }

        const {country, year, population } = data;

        const row = `${country},${year},${population}\r\n`;

        txtFile.write(row);

    })
    .on('end', function() {
        console.log('no pain, no gain');
    })
    .on('error', function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

csvFile.pipe(csvParser);
```

Comment: not the exact result really, but good enough for me to work with. Thanks

Comment: it reads csv and stores the results in the same format in txt file...?

Comment: Not exactly, the stored results look like this: 
country,year,population
USA
USA
...

So practically it only stores the country rows.

Comment: try the updated code